# Android: trying to show info based on what user profile has

Tags: android, listview, logic

I have a `ListView` and each row contains a different `User` object.

A `User` has these different fields:

- List of things I like
- List of things I hate
- List of games I play
- Description of myself

Now, when I populate the `ListView`, I want to show different things that each user has filled out. So for example, one row might show 'things I like' filled out, while another might show the 'description of myself'.

I don't want to adjacent rows to be showing the same type of row. All this code will be inserted into my `BaseAdapter's getView methood`.

What would be the best logic in terms of `pseudocode` to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

**Updated: Solution**

```
// Creates arraylist of elements that are complete in profile
List<String> profileElements = new ArrayList<String>();

if (user.getGameOwned() != null && user.getGameOwned().size() > 2) {
    profileElements.add(KEY_GAMES_PLAYED);
}
if (user.getAboutMe() != null && !user.getAboutMe().isEmpty()) {
    profileElements.add(KEY_ABOUT_ME);
}
if (user.getIAm() != null && user.getIAm().length > 2) {
    profileElements.add(KEY_I_AM);
}

if (profileElements.size() > 0) {
    String randomElement = profileElements.get(new Random().nextInt(profileElements.size() - 1));

    if (randomElement.equals(KEY_GAMES_PLAYED)) {
        // do whatever here
    }
    else if (randomElement.equals(KEY_ABOUT_ME)) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach, in your BaseAdapter put a verification if what list do you want to show.

For example:

```
int ctr = 1; // your counter - try to declare it on the global level

if(ctr<4){//your 4 types of list - 
     display(ctr); //print the current ctr
     ctr++;
}else{
     display(ctr);
     ctr = 1; //make the value to 1 for the next batch of loop
}
```

code:

```
display(int index){

    switch (index){
        case 1:
             //List of things I like
            break;
        case 2:
             //List of things I hate
            break;
        case 3:
            //List of games I play
            break;
        case 4:
             //Description of myself
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

You could also do random.nextInt(4) but it might have the same result each row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't do it as your code, but it gave me the idea how to do it. Posting the answer in my OP.

Comment: I glad to that it gives you idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do could be achieved using an ArrayAdapter and a custom row layout. It is well explained in  [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html). I'd recommend reading the whole thing but section 6 explains what you want to do.